# How can I convert this SQL to HQL query

Tags: c#, sql, hql

I have a query as follows:

```
WITH CTE AS (
  SELECT MIN(att.Date) [minDate]
  FROM Attendance att
  WHERE att.Date between '12/01/2011 00:00:00'
  AND '12/31/2011 00:00:00'
  AND att.EmpID = 4700
  GROUP BY EmpID, CONVERT(VARCHAR, att.Date , 111)
  HAVING MIN(CONVERT(VARCHAR, att.Date , 8)) > '09:00:00')
SELECT COUNT(minDate) FROM CTE
```

I need to use it in a C# application but I can't just use the query as it says that the query must start with a select or from keyword. I need this query to work in `HQL`. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

finally it worked with these

```
SELECT count(att.AttDate) 
from Attendance att 
where att.Employee.EmployeeCD = "+ empCD +" 
and att.AttDate IN 
  (SELECT MIN(att.AttDate) 
  from Attendance att 
  where att.AttDate between '" + startDate.Date + "' and '" + endDate.Date + "' 
  and att.Employee.EmployeeCD = " +  empCD + " 
  GROUP BY EmployeeCD, CONVERT(VARCHAR,att.AttDate, 111)
  having min(CONVERT(VARCHAR, att.AttDate, 8)) > '08:10:00')
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to rewrite the query.

In the result we do not care about date at all, what interest us is general result, so we can remove the date from select and replace it with EmpId*.

```
SELECT EmpID
  FROM Attendance att
  WHERE att.Date between '12/01/2011 00:00:00'
  AND '12/31/2011 00:00:00'
  AND att.EmpID = 4700
  GROUP BY EmpID, CONVERT(VARCHAR, att.Date , 111)
  HAVING MIN(CONVERT(VARCHAR, att.Date , 8)) > '09:00:00')
```

No we can change the question to something like this.

```
SELECT COUNT(EmpID) FROM Attendance WHERE EmpID IN (
  SELECT EmpID
      FROM Attendance att
      WHERE att.Date between '12/01/2011 00:00:00'
      AND '12/31/2011 00:00:00'
      AND att.EmpID = 4700
      GROUP BY EmpID, CONVERT(VARCHAR, att.Date , 111)
      HAVING MIN(CONVERT(VARCHAR, att.Date , 8)) > '09:00:00')
);
```

That second query rephrase only the CTE expression, that in most cases is only syntax sugar. Transforming this to HQL should not be a problem.

*I assume that EmpID is unique.

Comment: yes, empID is Uniq. and thanks a lot for helping me. but the query result is coming with all rows of that empID regardless all condition. i just need to count the rows that appear in your first query. plz help.

Comment: The first probably does that, but the second will return count. But for the example you have given the result will be null or 1. So if the query where condition are proper you do not really need that count at all.

Comment: let me elaborate. emp 4700 has 500 days of attendance in his work life. according to all conditions the second query result suppose to return the count of attendance between 12/1 to 12/31. so it suppose to return at best less than 31 right? but the query result is 500. his total attendance. now what?

Comment: i've found the problem, since the empID list contains 4700 for three times, so count matches with all and returns the count of all 4700 present in the table. so i went back to min(date) following your method and the result is ok. but now the problem is, while running the program, it returns an error. ("NHibernate.QueryException: in expected: att....) any help????

Comment: finally it is solved. counting min(date) works fine now. i worked following your query. thanx a lot bro.